# Output Expanding Sum and Reverse Expanded Sum in Python

Tags: python, function, loops, boolean

I'm attempting to write a function that displays the expanded sum and reverse expanded sum based on user's input in Python like so:

```
def printSum(int n, boolean reverse):
```

Where if the user enter the integer 4, 'true', the output is:

```
1+2+3+4 = 10
```

Or if the user enters the integer 4, 'false', the output is:

```
4+3+2+1 = 10
```

I know the code to reverse a given integer,

```
def reverse_int(n):
    Reverse = 0

    while(n > 0):
        Reminder = n %10
        Reverse = (Reverse *10) + Reminder
        n = n //10

    print("\n Reverse of entered number is = %d" %Reverse)
```

but I'm not sure how to apply it to the expanded/reverse expanded sum function described above. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: what would that flag do ? reversing in integer sum has no effect on result

Comment: You aren't reversing digits just the order of the numbers, `range()` can do things forwards `range(1, n+1)` or backwards `range(n, 0, -1)`... you can print them and sum them to get your result.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to reverse digits, instead use `range` to specify ordering of your output (forward and backward):

```
def printSum(n, reverse):
    s = sum(range(n+1))
    if reverse:
        print('+'.join(str(i) for i in range(1, n+1)) + ' = ' + str(s))
    else:
        print('+'.join(str(i) for i in range(n, 0, -1)) + ' = ' + str(s))

printSum(4, True)
# 1+2+3+4 = 10

printSum(4, False)
# 4+3+2+1 = 10
```